# testing angularjs directive that converts string to integer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, directive

well, I'm stuck on testing my directive:

```
angular.module('fooApp')
.directive('numericbinding', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                if (!scope.model) {
                    // inits with default val
                    scope.model = 0;
                } else if (scope.model && typeof scope.model === 'string') {
                    // console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + (typeof scope.model));
                    scope.model = parseInt(scope.model);
                    // console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + (typeof scope.model));
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Unit test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: numericbinding', function () {

    var $compile;
    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('fooApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, $httpBackend){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $compile = _$compile_;

        $compile('<form name="form1"><input numericbinding ng-model="someModel.Property" name="data"></input></form>')($rootScope);
    }));

    it('converts string value to integer', inject(function () {
        $rootScope.someModel.Property = '10';
        // $rootScope.form1.data.$setViewValue('10')
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect($rootScope.someModel.Property).toEqual(10);
    }));

}
```

Fails with msg:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux) Directive: numericbinding converts string value to integer FAILED
    Expected '10' to equal 10.
```

I've tested manually and `string` to `integer` conversion works OK. Still this particular test keeps failing.

Any idea what's wrong with that one?

**UPDATE:**

debugging in the chrome browser shows, that:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
```

is not triggered when I call: `$rootScope.$digest();` in my test. I even tried with: `$rootScope.$apply();` but still, no change here.

Comment: Have you tried with other browsers than PhantomJS?

Comment: @glepretre yes, the same problem is with chrome for me

Comment: Could you try changing `scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel,...` by `scope.$watch(model,...`? And is the output of your `console.log`s in your directive OK?